# Load multiple (lot of) objects from database , save it in ehcache and query it with primary key

Tags: java, oracle, ehcache

I have to process an xml file and for that I need to get around ~4k objects using it's primary key from a single table . I am using EhCache. I have few queries as follows:

1) It is taking lot of time if I am querying row by row based on Id and saving it in Cache . Can I query at initial point of time and save whole table in EHCache and can query it using primary key later in the processing

2) I dont want to use Query cache. As I can't load 4k objects at a time and loop it for finding correct object.

I am looking for optimal solution as right now my process is taking around 2 hours (it involves other processing too)

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole table and store it in a `Map<primary-key, table-row>` to reduce the overhead of the DB connection.

I guess a `TreeMap` is probably the best choice, it makes search for elements faster.

`Ehcache` is great to handle concurrence, but if you are reading the xml with a single process you don't even need it (just store the `Map` in memory).

Comment: Indeed, if you are using the data once for a specific purpose, you don't really need caching. You need a Map. However, not a `TreeMap`. That would be much slower. You are querying by id. HashMap is fine and faster. Or use a ConcurrentHashMap is you are doing parallel processing. Do an addAll on it. For Ehcache, there is a loadAll feature. But again, it doesn't feel like you need a caching framework.

Comment: Having 4k objects loaded in memory is not a good solution, i think